# UITableView Contents resets when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I simply don't understand how to fix this from what's out there.

It's fairly simple, I add a `UITextField` to my `UITableViewCell`. The user may type in it, then after scrolling it out and back into view the contents will be reset back to its default status.

This is to do with re-using old cells with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` right? I just don't understand how to fix it!

Here is my code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    //Stop repeating cell contents
    else for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) [view removeFromSuperview];

    //Add cell subviews here...

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to remove the cell contents once it is initialized they are never recreated, they are reused so your code should look like below

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


}
```

And I assume you want to have some controls onto your cell, in this case you can try using CustomCell which creates all the subviews on initializations.

Usually, all your initializations should be in

```
if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        //ALL INITS
    }
```

and outside it you should update the values you added into the cell..

Comment: Hmm, I had thought about this. Just put my code for adding subviews inside the if statement and now my table is just empty. Why would that be?

Comment: Solved it, I was using a cell identifier I had used in my storyboard. By using a unique one, it would add the subviews as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the inputted text back to the textfield, currently with reuse of cells, the textfield clears out the contents. You could try to store the textfield input in an nsstring property and in your cellforrow method, set the textfield text as that string, if the string has a valid value. That way, even on scrolling, the textfield will only display the user input that was stored into the nsstring property from the textfield.

Answer (score -1):

Before You follow my Answer i want to tell you that following code is bad for memory management because it will create new cell for each rows of `UITableView`, so be careful for it.

But it is better to use, When `UITableView` Have Limited rows *(about 50-100 may be )* then following code is helpful in your case. Use it, if it is suitable for you.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

         /// Put your code here.
     }

      /// Put your code here.

    return cell;
}
```

If you have limited rows then this is best code for you.