# UIImageView wrong rotation using CGAffineTransform

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uikit, cgaffinetransform

I have 4 sections, each section have 2 nested rows. I open the rows by tapping on each section.

When I tap on a section I want it accessory (`chevron.right`, made as `UIImageView`) be rotated clockwise by 90 degrees with a smooth animation and when I click again on the same section - rotate back, counterclockwise by 90 degrees.

I have a variable called `isOpened` (bool, false by default), which I change from false to true and back each tap in `didSelectRowAt`. Based on that a show all nested cells:

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      if indexPath.row == 0 {
        sections[indexPath.section].isOpened = !sections[indexPath.section].isOpened
        tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .none)
      }
   }
```

In the same method I try to rotate the chevron:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        sections[indexPath.section].isOpened = !sections[indexPath.section].isOpened
        tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .none)
        
        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MainSortTableViewCell else { return }

        if sections[indexPath.section].isOpened {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
                cell.chevronImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/2)
            }
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
                cell.chevronImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -.pi/2)
            }
        }
     }
```

But with this approach I face a couple of problems:

1. While first tap it animates chevron down on 90 degrees as I need, but when I tap again - it rotates **initial** chevron (face to the right) which causes a result as chevron looks up instead (-pi/2). How to fix the behaviour and rotate chevron from its new position (from when its face is down back to initial right)?
2. When I try to tap after first rotation the animation will be never triggered again. The transition is immediate. How to fix that?

Here is a GIF with the problem behaviour: [CLICK](https://cln.sh/TwqQCm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstood what the `transform` property means. `transform` represents the transformation of the view from its *original* position (facing right, in this case), and so setting it to `CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -.pi / 2)` makes the view transform in such a way that it rotates `-.pi / 2` radians from its *original* position, i.e. facing up.

To achieve the desired rotation, you can either *compose* this `-.pi/2` rotation with the current transform of the view, or just set `transform` to `.identity` (no transform at all, from its original position):

```
cell.chevronImage.transform = .identity
// or
cell.chevronImage.transform = cell.chevronImage.transform.rotated(by: -.pi / 2)
```

I suspect that you haven't added this rotation code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. *Please do that,* just without the animation. Otherwise you would run into problems like the chevron resetting after scrolling the table view ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18183485/5133585)). However, this would mean that it would be rotated too early, when you call `reloadSections`. The easiest way to solve this is to move `reloadSections` after the animation:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
    if sections[indexPath.section].isOpened {
        cell.chevronImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/2)
    } else {
        cell.chevronImage.transform = .identity
    }
} completion: {_ in
    self.tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .none)
}
```

Comment: Hi Sweeper! Thank you very much for such a detailed answer. I really misunderstood the concept of transform so thank you for clarifying it for me! Can I ask you one more detail: what if I need to open nested cells not after animation completion but in sync with it? Like if you try to do that in the Files app, chevron will be animated and nested cells will be shown simultaneously: https://cln.sh/z0LM6E As I guess I should reload sections in if/else statement where I rotate chevron, but it's not working properly: https://cln.sh/RtDczD

Comment: @artexhibit I feel that is a little too out of the scope of this question, which was mainly about `transform`. The first thing I would try is to use `insertRows` and `deleteRows` to just add/remove the rows you want, rather than reloading the entire section. This way you don't have to do it after the animation completes. If that doesn't work, I'd suggest that you post another question.